# Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so

Tags: ros, gazebo, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've built gazebo 1.9 from source followed by hydro desktop full from source in Ubuntu 13.10 following the instructions but I'm getting these errors when trying to use my xacro/urdf files

```
Error [Plugin.hh:138] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so: libgazebo_ros_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A few months ago I was able to do the same source install process and despite getting an error about `apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y gazebo2] failed` at the rosdep stage, the gazebo dependent packages built because I had correctly installed gazebo and pointed the right environmental variables at it.  And all that .so was there (or was it?), everything worked fine (even without it?).

I git cloned ros_control, realtime_tools, and control_toolbox but still no success at generating the so.  I'm not sure if those are actually needed here, but it some cursory research suggested they were, though on the earlier installs I never had to manually clone them (maybe rosdep did?).

Is there some other manual steps I need to do to get libgazebo_ros_control.so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157631/failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros_control.so/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might very well be the case that `gazebo_ros_control` is not available. If installed from binaries, you can check its presence with `dpkg -l ros-hydro-ros-control`. If building from source, try `rospack find gazebo_ros_control`.

Note that `gazebo_ros_control` lives in the [gazebo_ros_pkgs](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs) repository, and not part of `gazebo`, `ros_control` or `control_toolbox`. The latter are some of its dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/187417/problem-running-gazebo-failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros_controlso/?answer=187418#post-id-187418) worked for me on Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3